# Разное отображение элементов Crome FireFox?

Tags: php, css, google-chrome, firefox

Приветствую! Подскажите знающие. Есть фильтр на странице http://cosmeticprofi.com/uxod-za-licom/pilingi/. В браузере Firefox окошки сортировки отображаются с иконками выпадающего списка, а вот в Crome этих иконок нет. В чем может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: выложите [mcve]

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите css свойство `-webkit-appearance:none` у элемента `select` в файле `1513495196index.css`.

*Свойство -webkit-appearance — изменяет внешний вид кнопок и других элементов управления, чтобы походить на стандартные средства управления.*

Более подробную информацию вы можете узнать [тут](http://xiper.net/manuals/css-extensions/webkit/properties/webkit-appearance)